# voyager dashboard not showing posts users pages

Tags: laravel, voyager

I just installed voyager and the dashboard does not show posts, users, pages like you see on the screenshot.

[image]

can anyone please help 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need create new google_analystics _client_id by your account in console google and add in config